# How to delete child of "one-to-many" relationship? (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm looking to delete `scrapingAccount(db.model)` child from `botList(db.model)` parent. I can successfully delete the parent, but now I'm looking to delete the child. When I try to delete the child, an error pops up.

> **Not Found** The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

And when I go back to see if it deleted, it's still there. Not sure what's going on. Maybe it's the way I'm calling `/delete/{{account.id}}`... thoughts? How can I delete the child `scrapingAccount(db.model)` from parent `botList(db.model)`?

#### app.py

```
# Parent
class botList(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'botlist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    channel = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    bots = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    igUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    igPassword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    ytUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    ytPassword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    scrapingAccounts = db.relationship("scrapingAccount", backref="owner", lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Username %r>' % self.id
# Child
class scrapingAccount(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'scrapingaccount'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("botlist.id"))

# Delete Parent
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def deleteBot(id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        bot_to_delete = botList.query.get_or_404(id)
        try:
            db.session.delete(bot_to_delete)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "There was an error deleting a bot."
    else:
        bots = botList.query.order_by(botList.id)
        return render_template("botList.html", title=title, bots=bots)

# Delete Child
@app.route('/delete/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def deleteAccount(id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        account_to_delete = scrapingAccount.query.get_or_404(id)
        try:
            db.session.delete(account_to_delete.id)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return "There was an error deleting a bot."
            redirect('/update/<int:id>')
    else:
        redirect('/update/<int:id>')
```

#### index.html

```
# Form to delete parent
<tbody>
    {% for bot in bots -%}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ bot.username }} <a href="/update/{{bot.id}}">Update</a></td>
        <td>{{ bot.channel }}</td>
        <td>{{ bot.bots }}</td>
        <td>{{ bot.status }}<a href="/delete/{{bot.id}}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor -%}
</tbody>

# Form to delete child
{% for account in bot.scrapingAccounts %}
<form action="/update/{{bot.id}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="accountid" value="{{ account.id }}"/>
    <input type="text" name="igname" id="igname" placeholder="eg. Jane Doe" value="{{account.name}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="iguser" id="iguser" placeholder="eg. jandoe" value="{{account.username}}"/>
    <input type="submit" name="updateAccountButton" value="Update">
</form>
<a href="/delete/{{account.id}}">Delete</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you want to delete the object or only the relation? Also both `delete` functions are using the same `route`. This is not possible!

Comment: In addition, the wrong URL is given in the form. The input fields for "igname" and "iguser" are not needed. No method is specified within the route, so GET is used. You should use a POST or DELETE request to delete. However, a form does not support DELETE.

Comment: @rfkortekaas Delete child object

Comment: @Detlef I updated my script above. What should `<a>Delete</a>`'s href point to to delete the account? And do I have to remove `igname` and `iguser` if I want the delete button next to the update button shown here: https://i.imgur.com/YZqDKhk.png